# Equivalent of console.log to debug code in NextJS API routes?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm using nextjs API routes in my next app, and I have some code that runs when I send a POST request.

If the code that runs in the API route has errors or doesn't work right, I can't debug it because I can't use something like `console.log` to see what's happening because it won't log to the frontend page. Is there some alternative?

Maybe it would be in the network tab or involve throwing errors or sending something, I'm not sure.

Comment: `console.log` will log in your terminal, just take a look there!

Comment: I believe the OP is indicating that the standard `console.log` doesn't seem to work properly in the new App Router `route.ts` setup. Server standard out doesn't show anything at the terminal when invoking `console.log` in a POST method.  I too am having this same problem.

Comment: @bencodesall did you find a solution to the problem?

Comment: No answer, but I believe there was some wonky IoC/DI that was obfuscating the logging. Switched to using a DI'd Logger and solved the immediate need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NextJS's server will log to the terminal that's running `npm run dev` this isn't within the browser.

Try look there and see if it shows.

Comment: Yes Shanon. Not the browser, but in the terminal, of course.